# JAVA - how do i keep adding value

Tags: java

I have this button and a text field and i wanted to add value on the variable when the button is clicked everything is working apart from I'm unable to add value to string variable

For example if i put value 20 on tempvalue string it should have 20 and i put 30 it should have 50 but what i get is null2050.
I tried += operator which didn't work.

Isn't there any operator that keep adding value on top it or do i have to write new method ?

```
private String tempvalue;

btnEnter.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        String getTxt = textField.getText();
        tempvalue += getTxt;

        System.out.println(tempvalue);

    }
});
```

Comment: You show way too little code for us to see what is going wrong. What is "tempValue" ? What is "gtTxt" ?
Are they declared, are they initialized ? Do they have a value they refer to ?

Comment: You are concatenating strings instead of adding up numbers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You get Strings from Textfields.

```
String input = getTxt;
```

You have to parse the String to an integer or any other number type.

```
int value = Integer.parseInt(input);
```

Then you can do calculations.

You should also always check if the User Input really is a number.
Use try/catch to avoid wrong input:

```
int value = 0;
int firstValue = 5; //example variable
try{
    value = Integer.parseInt(input);
}catch(Exception e1){
    System.out.println("Your input could not be parsed to a number");
}
int result = firstValue + value; //always be sure all your values are numbers and not strings
System.out.println("Result: "+result);
```

In total:

```
private int tempvalue = 0;

btnEnter.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        String getTxt = textField.getText();
        int value = 0;

        try{
            value = Integer.parseInt(getTxt);
        }catch(Exception e1){
            System.out.println("Your input could not be parsed to a number");
        }

        tempvalue += value;

        System.out.println("Result: "+tempvalue);

        }
    });
}
```

Comment: thanks i will try your method. i'm used to visual basic and now i have to learn java which is just different for me so im struggling with java atm T_T.

Comment: I don't see where `firstValue` is being declared

Comment: @CandiedOrange `firstValue` was just an example to show the try/catch. The applied example for the user is the total example. But I declared it now.

Comment: thanks it works just change "catch(Exception e)" to "catch(Exception e1)" and it worked

Comment: Oh... I oversaw the `ActionEvent`, sorry

Answer (score 1):

You're simply concatenating your Strings.
In fact you start from `null` then you add `20` but as a String and then `30` but always as a String.
Transform in each step into a number and then you have your result done.

Answer (score 1):

As commented by @Jesper the code are concatenating strings and not applying computations such as sum, subtraction and son on ...

So, try out to change the code to convert from `java.lang.String` to `java.langInteger`

---

```
Integer tempValue += new Integer( getText );
System.out.println( tempvalue );
```

or using a static method from Integer wrap class

```
Integer tempValue += Integer.parseInt( getText );
System.out.println( tempvalue );
```

or then using a int Java type (with auto-box automatically)

```
int tempValue += Integer.parseInt( getText ).intValue();
System.out.println( tempvalue );
```

Be careful about string to integer conversions. This can rise a NumberFormatException on runtime.